# How to create 3 inputs in one line?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

In my code, I want each line to have only three input fields. However, when I attempt to create a fourth input field, the first input field remains on the previous line while the other three input fields move to the next line. After this, the code works correctly. The issue only arises with the first input field.

```js
let addButton = document.querySelector('.btn-group[aria-label="add-new-input"] button');
let deleteButton = document.querySelector('.btn-group[aria-label="delete-input"] button');
let buttonContainer = document.getElementById('button-container');

buttonContainer.style.display = 'flex';
buttonContainer.style.flexWrap = 'wrap';

let inputCounter = 1;
let rowCounter = 1;

addButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (inputCounter % 3 === 1) {
    let newRow = document.createElement('div');
    newRow.style.display = 'flex';
    newRow.id = 'row-' + rowCounter;
    buttonContainer.appendChild(newRow);
  }

  let newDiv = document.createElement('div');
  newDiv.className = 'input-group';
  newDiv.style.marginRight = '10px';

  let newInput = document.createElement('input');
  newInput.type = 'text';
  newInput.className = 'form-control';
  newInput.name = 'blocks' + inputCounter;
  newInput.placeholder = 'Blokları qeyd edin';
  newInput.ariaLabel = 'Input group example';
  newInput.ariaDescribedby = 'btnGroupAddon';

  newDiv.appendChild(newInput);

  let newAddButton = addButton.cloneNode(true);
  newAddButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    addButton.click();
  });

  let newDeleteButton = deleteButton.cloneNode(true);
  newDeleteButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    newDiv.parentNode.removeChild(newDiv);
    if (document.getElementById('row-' + rowCounter).childElementCount === 0) {
      document.getElementById('row-' + rowCounter).remove();
      rowCounter--;
    }
  });

  newDiv.appendChild(newAddButton);
  newDiv.appendChild(newDeleteButton);
  document.getElementById('row-' + rowCounter).appendChild(newDiv);

  if (inputCounter % 3 === 0) {
    rowCounter++;
  }
  inputCounter++;
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.1/css/all.min.css" />
<div class="btn-toolbar mb-3" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="blocks" placeholder="Mark the blocks" aria-label="Input group example" aria-describedby="btnGroupAddon">
  </div>

  <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="add-new-input">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-plus"></i></button>
  </div>

  <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="delete-input">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash-can fa-sm"></i></button>
  </div>

  <div id="button-container"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to restrict how many containers you have room for per line:

```
#button-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#button-container > div {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.input-group {
    margin-right: 10px;
    flex-basis: calc(33.33% - 10px); /* Adjust width to fit 3 per line */
}
```

```js
let addButton = document.querySelector('.btn-group[aria-label="add-new-input"] button');
let deleteButton = document.querySelector('.btn-group[aria-label="delete-input"] button');
let buttonContainer = document.getElementById('button-container');


let inputCounter = 1;
let rowCounter = 1;

addButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (inputCounter % 3 === 1) {
    let newRow = document.createElement('div');
    newRow.style.display = 'flex';
    newRow.id = 'row-' + rowCounter;
    buttonContainer.appendChild(newRow);
  }

  let newDiv = document.createElement('div');
  newDiv.className = 'input-group';
  newDiv.style.marginRight = '10px';

  let newInput = document.createElement('input');
  newInput.type = 'text';
  newInput.className = 'form-control';
  newInput.name = 'blocks' + inputCounter;
  newInput.placeholder = 'Blokları qeyd edin';
  newInput.ariaLabel = 'Input group example';
  newInput.ariaDescribedby = 'btnGroupAddon';

  newDiv.appendChild(newInput);

  let newAddButton = addButton.cloneNode(true);
  newAddButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    addButton.click();
  });

  let newDeleteButton = deleteButton.cloneNode(true);
  newDeleteButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    newDiv.parentNode.removeChild(newDiv);
    if (document.getElementById('row-' + rowCounter).childElementCount === 0) {
      document.getElementById('row-' + rowCounter).remove();
      rowCounter--;
    }
  });

  newDiv.appendChild(newAddButton);
  newDiv.appendChild(newDeleteButton);
  document.getElementById('row-' + rowCounter).appendChild(newDiv);

  if (inputCounter % 3 === 0) {
    rowCounter++;
  }
  inputCounter++;
});
```

```css
#button-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#button-container > div {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.input-group {
    margin-right: 10px;
    flex-basis: calc(33.33% - 10px); /* Adjust width to fit 3 per line */
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.1/css/all.min.css" />
<div class="btn-toolbar mb-3" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="blocks" placeholder="Mark the blocks" aria-label="Input group example" aria-describedby="btnGroupAddon">
  </div>

  <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="add-new-input">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-plus"></i></button>
  </div>

  <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="delete-input">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash-can fa-sm"></i></button>
  </div>

  <div id="button-container"></div>
</div>
```

Also I suggest you clone your elements instead of creating them over and over

Here I additionally added delegation from the container and added the classes add and delete to the local buttons and IDs to the main buttons

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const addButton = document.getElementById('add');
  const deleteButton = document.getElementById('delete');
  const container = document.getElementById('container');
  const template = document.getElementById('template');
  const maxGroups = 3;
  deleteButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    console.log('delete what?');
  });
  addButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const clonedContent = template.content.cloneNode(true);
    const lastRow = container.lastElementChild;
    const newRow = !lastRow || lastRow.querySelectorAll('.input-group').length === maxGroups; // add row if no row or maxGroup inputs
    if (newRow) {
      container.appendChild(clonedContent); // create a new row
    } else {
      lastRow.appendChild(clonedContent.querySelector('.input-group')); // append the input-group to last row
    }
  })
  container.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const tgt = e.target;
    const parent = tgt.closest('.input-group');
    const row = parent && parent.closest('.row');
    if (!parent) return; // not inside a group
    const button = e.target.closest('button');
    if (button && button.matches('.delete')) {
      parent.remove(); // remove the parent
      if (!row.querySelector('.input-group')) row.remove(); // no more groups
    } else if (button && button.matches('.add')) {
      console.log("add", parent.querySelector('[name=blocks1]').value)
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#button-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#button-container>div {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.input-group {
  margin-right: 10px;
  flex-basis: calc(33.33% - 10px);
  /* Adjust width to fit 3 per line */
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.1/css/all.min.css" />
<div class="btn-toolbar mb-3" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="blocks" placeholder="Mark the blocks" aria-label="Input group example" aria-describedby="btnGroupAddon">
  </div>

  <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="add-new-input">
    <button type="button" id="add" class="btn btn-light"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-plus"></i></button>
  </div>

  <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="delete-input">
    <button type="button" id="delete" class="btn btn-light"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash-can fa-sm"></i></button>
  </div>

  <div id="container"></div>
</div>
<template id="template">
<div class="row">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="blocks1" placeholder="Blokları qeyd edin" aria-label="Input group example"><button type="button" class="btn btn-light add"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-plus"></i></button><button type="button" class="btn btn-light  delete"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash-can fa-sm"></i></button>
  </div>
</div>
</template>
```

Clicking 3 times and typing 1,2,3
then clicking 3 more times and typing 4,5,6 gives me this

[image]

Comment: Thank you for replying. I copied and pasted your code, but when I press the ‘+’ button, there is no reaction

Comment: I wrapped it in a load function now. Perhaps you pasted it before the elements existed or perhaps you did not add the IDs I did

Comment: `<button type="button" id="add"` and `<button type="button" id="delete"` - I do not know what you want to do with the main delete button.

Comment: I’m working on Django and I want to retrieve all input data from HTML. Initially, there should be one input field. However, if I want to add a new input field, I can click the ‘+’ button. Let’s say I have six inputs. In that case, there should be two lines with three inputs on each line.

Comment: As in my second example, no?

Comment: Yes, my code works correctly. The only problem is that when I create three inputs on the first line, everything is okay. However, when I create a fourth input, the last three inputs move to the second line, but the first input remains on the first line. I would like to share an image. Could you provide your Gmail address?

Comment: My information is in my [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/295783/mplungjan), but see the image I added too